# Why does Copi / Cohen call "Othello believes that Desdemona loves Cassio" a compound statement?

Tags: logic

Copi's Introduction to Logic states  that a compound statement is one which consists of 2 or more statements as components. A component is defined as a part of a compound statement that is itself a statement, and if replaced in the compound statement by another statement, the result is meaningful.

The text states that:

> Othello believes that Desdemona loves Cassio

is a compound statement with the component "Desdemona loves Cassio".

I understand how the replacement of such a statement with another statement, e.g. "The sky is blue", is meaningful. But that would imply that "Othello" believes that" is also a component and a statement.

The replacement of this statement with another is meaningless. e.g. "The sky is blue Desdemona loves Cassio".

Is the text right in saying this is a compound statement?

Comment: I agree with you; a "compund" statement must be composed of parts that may "stand alone" i.e. that are meaningful also by itself: "Othello believes that" is not by itself a complete statement.

Comment: Usually "belief" is formalized through a [belief operator](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/): **BcA** reads "Agent **c** believes **A**" where **A** is a statement. **BcA** works as a *quantifier* and thus in isolation it is not a statement.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Desdemona loves Cassio. At least, Othello believes that.  How is the latter not a complete statement?  It is not independent, but it is complete.  Pronouns are not part of the issue with compound or complex sentences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about grammar, and the vocabulary used to discuss grammar in a particular context, rather than about logic or a more comprehensive theory of grammar.

Comment: In standard English grammar, a sentence is "compound" if it is two independent clauses joined by "and," "but" or "or." A "complex" sentence is one that has an independent clause ("Othello believes") and a dependent clause ("that Desdemona loves Cassio"). Therefore, this sentence is a complex sentence.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

*Maybe you have to check again the details* ...

Compare with:

- Irving Copi, [Symbolic Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=rEjuAAAAMAAJ) (4th ed., 1973), page 8:

> A *simple* statement is one which does not contain any other statement as a 
>   component part, whereas every *compound* statement does contain another 
>   statement as a component part.

According to this definition, both the *conjunction*:

> "Roses are red and violets are blue"

and:

> "Smith believes that lead is heavier than zinc"

are *compound* statements.

Then we have:

> Any compound statement whose truth value is completely determined by the truth values of its component statements is a *truth-functionally compound* statement.

According to this further classification, the first one is a *truth-functionally compound* statement while the second - as well as "Othello believes that Desdemona loves Cassio" - is not.

---

See Irving M. Copi & ‎Carl Cohen, *Introduction to Logic*, (1990), page 255:

> A compound statement is one that does contain another statement as a component. [...] The notion of a component of a statement is fairly straightforward, although it is not exactly the same as "a part that is itself a statement."

Thus, in "Othello believes that Desdemona loves Cassio", the part "Othello believes" is **not** a statement.